# SQL query - pattern matching for any date in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working with Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

I want to display the result if any record in my table contains any date in it.
For Example:If a record exists with value GT3429062020HYHK(since it has 29062020 in it which is today's date), then the query should return that particular record.

Comment: Are all of the dates formatted identically to the one in the example?

Comment: @Oso Yes,All the dates are in that exactly particular format(ddmmyyyy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dates you're searching for are guaranteed to be in the form DDMMYYYY (as in your example), you can check for it with

```
target_column LIKE '%[0123][0-9][01][0-9][12][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

This looks for the following pattern:

0-3 (the tens part of the day)
0-9 (the ones part of the day)
0|1 (the tens part of the month)
0-9 (the ones part of the month)
1|2 (thousands part of the year)
0-9 x 3 (the remaining year digits)

If your dates are all guaranteed to occur in this century, you could further refine it to

```
target_column LIKE '%[0123][0-9][01][0-9]20[012][0-9]%'
```

Comment: @SriLakshmanaTeja if it worked for you, you should mark it as an answer.

Comment: @Oso What is the pattern if the date format is yyyymmdd ?

Comment: Move the last four spaces representing the year to the front, and swap the DD and MM: `'%[12][0-9][0-9][0-9][01][0-9][0123][0-9]%'`

Comment: @Oso, here it is picking the date with value 35052020(ddmmyyyy) which should not be the case since that date not exists. Can you review your logic?

Comment: @SriLakshmanaTeja You can't make a single statement in SQL Server 2008 that will only match *valid* dates in a string, you'll need several conditional statements. Given that my answer explains how the pattern works, this would be a good opportunity for you to figure out how to structure them. You'll either need separate matches for Month+DayNumber combinations (including a second February pattern for leap years), or you'll need to extract the string and see if you can successfully convert it to a date. I recommend option 2, it's harder but will be shorter and less repetitive.

Comment: @Oso,Thanks for that