# SQL Query: How to check if a particular record had more alphabets than numbers and return that

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I am working with Microsoft SQL Server 2014.

I want to display the result if a particular record had more alphabets than numbers with the help of a SQL Query.

For Example:If a table had column 'CustomerName' and it had value "ALeX143ForU"(since it had more alphabets than numbers), then the query should return that particular record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bit unusual, but you can try this below logic-

[Demo Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=a193a5023777287f07475fca3fe99bea)

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table_name
WHERE
-- Below is calculating String LEN only for Alphabet
LEN(
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
    your_column_name,'0',''),'1',''),'2',''),'3',''),'4',''),'4',''),'6',''),'7',''),'8',''),'9','')
) 
>
-- Calculate LEN for Integer value only
(
    -- Full string LEN
    LEN(your_column_name) -
    -- LEN for only alphabet
    LEN(
       REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
    your_column_name,'0',''),'1',''),'2',''),'3',''),'4',''),'4',''),'6',''),'7',''),'8',''),'9','')
    )
)
```

Comment: Can you please check the Logic as it is not working. I am not getting the desired result.FYI, I had 'CustomerName' column in 'Customers' Table which contains Username of Customers.I want to display the list of Customers whose Username had more alphabets than numbers.(As mentioned in the above Example).

Comment: @SriLakshmanaTeja the logic should work. can you check the demo - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=a193a5023777287f07475fca3fe99bea

Comment: Sorry..My bad..It is working Perfect. Any chances of optimizing the query?

Comment: @SriLakshmanaTeja Nice to see that it worked and helped. Please don't forget to put an up vote as well :)

Comment: @SriLakshmanaTeja - as per my knowledge, the optimization option is available from MSSQL server 2017. A new method TRANSLATE is added from that version, where you can easily check the same logic.

Comment: mkRabbani, Here, the problem with the logic is that it is picking the records that contains only alphabets in it. For Example: It is picking the record with Username='AZIZBHAI' but that should not happen.

Comment: ohh, let me check the issue.

Comment: Just added one more logic, please check here - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=5011be041531d59478b967d110c0013e aziz vai should not mind now ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot @mk . Can you help on this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62640608/sql-query-pattern-matching-for-any-date-in-a-string/62640809?noredirect=1#comment110776314_62640809

Comment: Checking the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216915/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-sri-lakshmana-teja).